# Apache Solr Reindexing not working with huge set of records

Tags: solr, reindex

I'm trying to reindex records in solr collection to a new collection using collections api and for a collection with 6000 records it is working fine and within 5 minutes all documents in source collection is getting copied to target collection.
But when I tried to reindex a collection with 3 million records its not working. When I checked the status of reindexing its giving following response

```
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":11},
  "reindexStatus":{
    "actualSourceCollection":"my-collection",
    "actualTargetCollection":"my-collection-copy",
    "checkpointCollection":".rx_ck_my-collection",
    "daemonName":"my-collection-copy",
    "daemonUrl":"http://localhost:8983/solr/my-collection_shard1_replica_n1",
    "inputDocs":3197842,
    "phase":"copying documents",
    "processedDocs":0,
    "state":"running"}}
```

I waited for around 5 hours, but no document is being copied. I even tried with multiple options like increasing shards and replica set, but no luck.

I'm running solr in cloud mode with two nodes and my source collection has two shards and two replica sets.

I"m using version 8.2

When I checked the logs, I didn't see any errors. The same process is working fine for collection with less number of records.

I'm executing reindex process as an asynchronous task. Following is the command I'm using for reindexing
**/solr/admin/collections?action=REINDEXCOLLECTION&name=my-first-collections&target=my-first-collections-copy&async=1000**

Any help to debug the issue will be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was doing reindexing operation for an updated schema and in the new schema I made a field mandatory which is not present in already existing documents and when I tried copying all values to a new collection which has updated schema configuration, it is failing in mandatory field condition.So reindexing is not happening.

Though in Solr I didn't find any error status or error logs for reindexing operation, Instead it is continuously showing copying documents as status.

It would have been easier if solr is throwing some error for this case